# C# .net 5 - OnModelCreating Entity owned by multiple Entities

Tags: c#, .net-5, ef-fluent-api

I'm having issues with understanding Fluent API when it comes to multiple entities owning one class.

**Error:**

```
The type 'City' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.
```

I have three entities; `Country`, `City` and `User`.

`Country` and `City` get seeded with the `HasData()` method by migrations from a file. `User` is created by the end-users, the City property can be `null`.

```
public class Country : Entity
{
    public List<City> Cities { get; init; }

    public Country()
    {
        Cities = new List<City>();
    }

}


public class City : Entity
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; init; }
    public City()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

}



public class User : Entity
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}
```

Now my basic OnModelCreating contains:

```
    builder.Entity<Country>(c =>
    {
        c.HasData(countriesList.ToArray());

        c.OwnsMany(x => x.Cities)
            .HasData(LoadCities(countryToLoadCities));
    });
```

But I'm not sure how I can write it to understand the "`User.City`" property as desired. I've tried multiple options both with a direct Navigational property, a foreign key + nav property and a object in between `UserCity`. But migrations keeps throwing errors my way, and I'm not sure what it wants me to do.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Ignore<Entity>();

    //Load all country codes
    Country countryToLoadCities = null;
    var countriesList = LoadCountries(out countryToLoadCities);
    
    builder.Entity<Country>(c =>
    {
        c.HasData(countriesList);
        var b = c.OwnsMany(x => x.Cities);
        b.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(x => x.CountryID);
        b.HasData(LoadCities(countryToLoadCities));
        b.Ignore(x => x.Users);
        //b.OwnsMany(x => x.Users).WithOwner().HasForeignKey(f => f.CityID);

    });

    builder.Entity<Guild>(g => {
        g.OwnsMany(x => x.Channels).WithOwner().HasForeignKey(q => q.GuildID);
        var userBuilder = g.OwnsMany(x => x.Users);
        userBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(q => q.GuildID);
        userBuilder.HasOne(u => u.City).WithMany().HasForeignKey(q => q.CityID);

    });
}
```

Comment: It's not an answer - more like suggestions to get to the answer. 1. Why do you need to derive from Entity? these are POCO classes. 2. User and City have one-to-many relationship, right? then City needs to have list of Users. 3. In one-to-many entities it is typical to have ID field in addition to object itself. So, City would have CountryId. 4. Probably, put your DbContext class as well. Finally, and advice. I usually create a database with all the tables and foreign keys - and then run scaffolding to get the baseline of objects. Simplifies a lot!

Comment: thanks @Felix. 1. These are my "Model" objects, but "Entity" atm is just a parent with an "ID". 2. Although User & City are one-to-many. The data model would never care or query City > all users. Implementing 3 & 4

Comment: now you have Guild?! that's new! Also, you didn't put DbContext - and while typically I can infer what is in it - your model is so convoluted, that I am not sure any more. I don't even understand where you get the error from. Again - my advice: create a database with all the tables that you have in the model, and scaffold the model. Then start with *that* model, and make the needed changes, if any. Based on your code, I am not even sure that you will need any changes!

Comment: Oh - and "Entity is just a parent with an ID". Huh? and how this ID will be generated - in addition to CityID, CountryID, etc.? You are *really* asking for trouble

Comment: @Felix thanks, Reverse Engineering is indeed useful. Didn't even realize that was possible in .NET Core. Would you mind posting your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you need to derive from Entity? these are POCO classes.
2. User and City have one-to-many relationship, right? then City needs to have list of Users.
3. In one-to-many entities it is typical to have ID field in addition to object itself. So, City would have CountryId.

Probably, put your DbContext class as well. And "Entity is just a parent with an ID". Huh? and how this ID will be generated - in addition to CityID, CountryID, etc.? You are really asking for trouble

Advice. I usually create a database with all the tables and foreign keys - and then run scaffolding to get the baseline of objects. Simplifies a lot!

Then start with that model, and make the needed changes, if any. Based on your code, I am not even sure that you will need any changes!